# Why can't \textffm{} be used in the title of l3doc document class?

Tags: xetex, l3doc, ltxdockit

`\textffm{}` can be used in `\title{}` in `ltxdoc` document class, but `l3doc` can't. Why?

```latex
% \documentclass{ltxdoc}
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{fetamont}
\begin{document}
\title{\textffm{TEST}}
\maketitle
\textffm{TEST}
\end{document}
```

```latex
LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

! Argument of \@tforloop has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.9 \end{document}

?
```

`\textffm{}` can be used in the text of `l3doc`.

```latex
\documentclass{l3doc}
\usepackage{fetamont}
\begin{document}
\textffm{TEST}
\end{document}
```

Is this a bug of `l3doc`? Or is there other consideration? If `l3doc` doesn't fix this problem temporarily, is there any way to allow `\textffm{}` to be used in `title{}`?

Comment: A workaround is to use `\title{\ffmfamily TEST}`

Answer (score 2):

`l3doc` loads `hyperref`, and that means we need to tell `hyperref` to skip over the command. I would use

```latex
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\textffm\textsf}
```